# Microsoft documentation - what's the difference between "Win32 AD" and "Windows Protocol AD"?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I was given an AD server to work with and I encountered the attribute MaxPwdAge which is negative. I turned to the documents and found two contradicting results that both claims to be some form of "Active Directory Schema". What is the difference between the two?

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-maxpwdage
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/49fecab6-8d35-4a9a-8cd3-ceec7093486a

Answer (score 0):

I've seen both sets of documentation, and from what I have seen, they're both describing the same thing, just in different ways.

The [top of the Attributes section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/active-directory-schema) in the "Win32" documentation says:

> The following topics provide lists of the types of attributes defined by Active Directory.

The [top of that section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/e20ebc4e-5285-40ba-b3bd-ffcb81c2783e) in the Open Specifications documentation says something similar:

> Specifies the Active Directory Schema Attributes M, which contains a partial list of the objects that exist in the Active Directory schema (attributes beginning with M).

The Open Specifications documentation seems to cover a far bigger range of topics, where the AD schema is only a small part.

Comment: If we're purely looking at the definition, the first one is of an Interval type, which in turn is an unsigned long, and the second one is a *negative* integer.